# command line of process by name

Tags: windows, cmd

I used the following command in cmd to get the process command line.  It gives details of all processes:

```
WMIC /OUTPUT:C:\ProcessList.txt PROCESS get Caption,Commandline,Processid
```

I want to get the details of a particular process by name in a note pad.  Thanx.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the WHERE clause. But you didn't bother to say what process you were looking for.

If you know the processId you could use something like.

```
WMIC /OUTPUT:"C:\ProcessList.txt" process where processid=8196 get Caption,Commandline,Processid
```

An alternative to the /output option is to simply redirect the output. If you know the caption, then you can use something like:

```
>"c:\ProcessList.txt" wmic process where "caption='chrome.exe'" get caption,commmandLine,processId
```

The WHERE clause uses SQL syntax - strings are in single quotes. You can use complex logic and wild cards. The `%` matches any 0 or more characters, and `_` matches any one character.

```
>"c:\ProcessList.txt" wmic process where "caption like 'c%.ex_' and processId<5000" get caption,commandLine,processId
```